# Display a single post on a publishing site

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog, sub-site

I am using a Content Query Web Part to display Blog posts on my homepage(a publishing site). My question is how can I

1. Compose my post URL to point to another sub-site(a publishing site also) and make 
   the post content be displayed in a content query web part.
2. Use the Content Query Web Part pick the `post_id` from the URL

E.g user clicks on this url

```
        <a href="http://domain/publishingsubsite?post_id=4">Read More</a>
```

The `post_id` is picked by my sub-site and displayed with a content query webpart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by following the tutorial link pasted below

http://www.bjw.co.nz/developer/sharepoint-2010/1174-how-to-display-a-single-list-item-on-a-sharepoint-page

Answer (score 0):

You can filter Content Query WebPart using Query String (in your case `post_id`)

For that

1. Edit the webpart and in the Additional Filters section.
2. Add a filter which says "ID" `is equal to` [PageQueryString: post_id]
3. Save and stop editing the page

Comment: There is no "ID" filter in the additional filters section of the content query web part

Comment: By ID I mean what ever field you want to filter.

Comment: I understand you now, but I am targetting the post ID itself. here is a sample of a single post url on my blog http://exserv/news/Lists/Posts/Posts.aspx?ID=6. How do I filter this ID in my cqwp to pick posts by it